# Help center search doesn't find the homework page

Tags: bug, help-center, search

I've noticed an issues with the help center search, it fails to find a specific help center post with obvious keywords.

The post is [the homework page on Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework),  [a search for "homework" in the help center](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=homework) doesn't find it even though it contains the work "homework" several times.

Comment: I've also noticed that the help center is often unhelpful (e.g. on homework). Searching for "homework" the only hit I get is ["Privilege: create posts - Ask a question or contribute an answer"](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts).

Comment: http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/550/why-is-the-homework-policy-hard-to-find-in-the-help-pages